# Datasource in create and "normal mode for the same form

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to create a single form that I can bind to a datasource in create mode and in "normal mode". The use case is that I can have an existing item in the datasource that I would like to edit, or I would like to create a new one.

I can't find a way to dynamically switch the datasource mode before opening the form. It seems that 2 forms are required to accomplish this.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reuse form fields, but you'll still need at least two forms (containers). The idea is to create a page fragment with datasource derived from some model:
[image: Fields]

then you can add this page fragment to form (container) and ***override*** datasource.

[image: Form]

Normally you would choose between normal mode:

```
@datasource.item
```

...and create mode:

```
@datasource.modes.create.item
```

You can find complete code sample in [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/) template and learn more about create mode in docs:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#create_mode_datasource